# How to put node modules into rollup bundle?

Tags: javascript, rollup, rollupjs

Have a simple rollup config, like this.

```
export default {
    input: 'src/index.js',
    output: {
        file: 'build/index.js',
        format: 'cjs'
    },
    external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'prop-types', 'emotion'],
    plugins: [
        resolve({
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
        }),
        commonjs(),
        babel({
            include: 'node_modules/**'
        })
    ]
};
```

I wanna have rollup to build node_modules and put them into bundle, but I got an error `Unexpected token` for jsx, seems like it cannot process the jsx syntax, however if I don't include node_modules in babel plugin, it works well. So what's the right way to build node_modules with rollup?

Answer (score 0):

Put the Babel plugin before the CommonJS one — the transforms run in order, and the CommonJS doesn't know how to parse JSX, so the Babel one needs to happen first.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Yeah, I tried to order them differently. But still it doesn't work

Comment: Should've mentioned that I use babel 7.

Comment: Are you certain that the Babel plugin is correctly configured?